# Similar function to STContains in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Since the geo-spacial function called STContains is only available in SQL Server 2012, what's the similar function I can use to get the same or similar results in SQL Sever 2008?

Is STIntersects feasible option?

Cheers!

Comment: What makes you think it isn't available in 2008? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933904(v=sql.100).aspx) says it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STContains` **IS** available in SQL Server 2008.

```
DECLARE @s0 AS GEOMETRY = 'POLYGON((4 4, 7 4, 7 7, 4 7 ,4 4))'
DECLARE @s1 AS GEOMETRY = 'POLYGON((5 4.2, 6 4.2, 6 5, 5 5, 5 4.2))'

SELECT *
 FROM (
    SELECT @s0 AS 'Geo', 'S0' as 'Labels'
    UNION ALL   SELECT @s1, 'S1'
 ) AS A
 WHERE A.Geo.STContains(@S1) = 1
```

[See SQL-Fiddle-Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7762/0)

Comment: Hey Nico! I guess the confusion is that I was using geography type parameter in STContains function so, I ended up using STIntersect:

Comment: How does this work when you're using existing features in a spatial table, ie. not creating the geometry from scratch with each query?

Comment: The OP references this fact in their comment but you may want to clarify that `STContains` exists only for the **GEOMETRY** data-type in SQL 2008 and not for the **GEOGRPAHY** data-type.  `STIntersect` seems to be a good alternative in most of the cases that I have encountered.